# VC 2019 c# how include sources of DLL compiled in debug:full from other project to enable full source code navigation

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

i have a simple c# app that is using DLL from another project which is compiled with debug: full mode
i can step into the code of the DLL but when I'm in the source code i can't click + jump to other source code that is related to the DLL.
how do i configure Visual Studio 2019 to be able to fully navigate the DLL I'm referencing
this is by the way is enable somehow by default in VC++

Comment: Disable `Just My Code`?

Comment: did it not working ... see comments below

Comment: If you debug  a c++ dynamic dll, you should make sure that you have enabled native code debugging. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019). If it is a c# dll, you should right-click on the solution-->Properties-->Debug source files and then input the folder path of the debugging source cs files.

Comment: did it , still only the first source

Comment: delete `.vs` hidden folder, any output files and then rebuild the project again to test it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment/suggestion, but I needed multiple lines, check out the following

1. The other DLL needs to be built using the same framework version as the code you are searching from
2. as Paval said in Tools -> Options... -> Debugging -> General make sure the "Enable Just My Code" is not selected
3. When you are in 'source code' make sure the PDB for the dll you are referencing is in the build directory for the selected configuration

Comment: I disabled it, the PDB is in the  DEBUG directory of the DLL 
i disabled the "Just My Code"  still i can debug to the first source of the DLL 
but can't jump to other sources from this source

Comment: also when i just click the DLL source with RMB + class name it jump to the metadata not the DLL source